# Prove that R∪S is an equivalence relation on A∪B. A and B are disjoint.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

I understand the basics of equivalence relations, but I'm having trouble with the proof.  I started with saying if a ∈ R, and R is an equivalence relation on A, therefore, a ∈ A, and (a,a) ∈ R and A.  I have the same sort of start for S, but I can't figure out how to tie the two together if they are disjoint.  Here is the proof below:

Suppose R is an equivalence relation on A, S is an equivalence relation on B, and A and B are disjoint.
Prove that R∪S is an equivalence relation on A∪B.

Comment: The disjointness of $A$ and $B$ isn’t a hindrance: it’s needed in order to show that $R\cup S$ is transitive.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have the right idea for reflexivity, but what you wrote is unclear.  It would be better to write something like this:  If $x \in A \cup B$, then either $x \in A$ or $x \in B$.  If $x \in A$, then $(x,x) \in R$ because $R$ is a reflexive relation on $A$, so $(x,x) \in R \cup S$.  If $x \in B$ then a similar argument applies, so in either case we have $(x,x) \in R \cup S$, showing that $R \cup S$ is a reflexive relation on $A \cup B$.

A similar argument works to show that $R \cup S$ is a symmetric relation on $A \cup B$, using the fact that $R$ and $S$ are both symmetric.  So far we do not need to use the hypothesis that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint.

To show that $R \cup S$ is a transitive relation, as Brian commented, we do need the hypothesis that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint.  Suppose that $(x,y),(y,z)\in R \cup S$.  It is straightforward to show that $(x,z) \in R \cup S$ using the transitivity of $R$ and $S$, provided that we first use the disjointness of $A$ and $B$ to rule out the case that $(x,y) \in R$ and $(y,z) \in S$ or vice versa.